# How do I represent postgres `bytea` type in slick 2.0.1?

Tags: postgresql, scala, blob, slick, bytea

In slick's documentation it's said that `java.sql.Blob` is one of types supported out of the box and I'm attempting to use it to represent `bytea` column. But the following code gives me an error:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import java.sql.{ Timestamp, Blob }

case class Test(id: Int, last_updated: Timestamp, data: Blob)

class Tests(tag: Tag) extends Table[Test](tag, "tests") {
  def data = column[Blob]("data")
  def last_updated = column[Timestamp]("last_updated")
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def * = (id, last_updated, data)
}
```

The error message is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given types. Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported 
     type in a Query (e.g. scala List). Required level: scala.slick.lifted.ShapeLevel.Flat Source type: (scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int], scala.slick.lifted.Column[java.sql.Timestamp], 
     scala.slick.lifted.Column[java.sql.Blob]) Unpacked type: utils.Test Packed type: Any
    - implements scala.slick.lifted.AbstractTable.$times
    - type mismatch; found : (scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int], scala.slick.lifted.Column[java.sql.Timestamp], scala.slick.lifted.Column[java.sql.Blob]) required: 
     scala.slick.lifted.ProvenShape[utils.Test]
    - type mismatch; found : (scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int], scala.slick.lifted.Column[java.sql.Timestamp], scala.slick.lifted.Column[java.sql.Blob]) required: 
     scala.slick.lifted.ProvenShape[utils.Test]
```

What is going on and how can I correctly represent `bytea` in slick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not related to `Blob` support. As the error message suggests as the most common reason, "T in Table[T] does not match your * projection". It should be `def * = (id, last_updated, data) <> (Test.tupled, Test.unapply _)`.

Note that this will still not work for `bytea`. Slick's PostgreSQL driver maps `Blob` to the blob type from PotgreSQL's "lo" extension. You need to use `Array[Byte]` for `bytea`.